# Convert a string to gameobject that is inactive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a GameObject that is Inactive namely emptyShape1 and I created a function that returns a string namely emptyShape1.

I tried converting that string to GameObject using casting

```
(GameObject)emptyShape1
```

so that I can activate that emptyShape1 GameObject but it gives me an error saying

> cannot convert string to Unity.GameObject

I tried using GameObject.Find(emptyShape1) but it also gives me an error saying

> Object reference not set to an instance of Object

What is the efficient way to find or convert emptyShape1 string to GameObject?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/201189/convert-gameobject-to-string.html

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/890636/find-an-inactive-game-object.html
look the second answer. Warning you need to know its parent.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood, you want to find an inactive GameObject with a specific name. I don't think you can do this with GameObject.Find, I think it's possible to find it if you have its parent object;

```
parent.transform.Find("emptyShape1");
```

---

Old answer:

How to create a GameObject with a specific name, and disable it:

```
GameObject emptyGameObject = new GameObject(enemyShape1);
emptyGameObject.setActive(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find all objects with `Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<SomeType>();` which returns an array, and then look for the one with the name - however it is an expensive call.  Is there no way your code could be altered to keep a list of disabled items that you want to call back?